# Portable Windows Development Environment and USB Thumb Drives

Tags: development-environment, portability, usb-drive

I find myself wasting more and more time the last few years when I have to reinstall an OS and 20+ development tools and apps. I'm looking to do more work in virtual machines.

Now that you are starting to see 32GB and 64GB thumb drives. I was wondering can you run a Virtual PC or VMWare image from a USB Thumb drive? Any issues with doing this? I would plan on backing up the image daily just in case something happened to the drive.

Comment: do you mean putting the virtual disk file (VHD / vmdsk) in the thumb drive, or do you mean using entire drive as (directly) the disk for VM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502319/carrying-and-working-on-an-entire-development-box-from-a-usb-stick-feasible

Comment: Francis, can you explain the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Running a VM off a flash drive would have positively putrid performance. I guess you could copy the virtual hard drive to local storage first, though. I run my VMs off an external hard drive, myself.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried a thumb drive, but I use external USB drives for virtual machines all the time.  I use VirtualPC 2007 and have had no problems.  In fact, sometimes if the host machine is on the weaker side, having the VM on an external drive increases performance.  I recommend the external USB drive route.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's the western digital brand of external hard drive.  I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you invest in an external SSD to put those VMs on. Thumb drives are not known for speed.

Comment: I do not have eSATA on my machine only USB 2.0. Do you think something like this would be worth it - http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820411002 Might upgrade my machine in the next year. Would the USB 2.0 defeat the whole purpose of the SSD?

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely doable. Take a look at [VMware Player -- To Go](http://mcpmag.com/columns/article.asp?editorialsid=1500). Performance will be worse than an internal hard drive but not completely terrible. Jeff did a [brief comparison](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001127.html).

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP (and Vista and 7) can boot on multiple hardware configurations, each with different drivers (retail license, not OEM).

I started out with a 2.5" USB HDD for my portable enviroment. It was booting fine on multiple machines (@home, @work, or in any VMWare).

I don't recommend a flash stick, but I do recommend a SSD stick. Today you can find SSD sticks with 2 ends, one USB and one eSATA.

For booting USB drives with Windows XP you need [USBoot](http://usboot.org).
After booting the first time, Windows will install some drivers, including the Disk Controller drivers (without which, if booting directly on SATA Windows would BSOD with 0x0000007b).

Since the first Intel SSD came out, I switched to using a SSD.
I have 2 2.5" trays (insert 2.5" drive like a floppy) both @home and @work.

I can boot that Windows in VMWare and on many other computers using USB (and I have, and it was life saving). I even booted from the backup VHD once :)

I use Windows Backup to backup to a versioned VHD (in command line, see wbadmin command on Windows Vista, 7, 2008, 2008 R2).
I can restore the entire enviroment including the OS pretty fast, and I have recovered from several disasters.

I also use EFS for important files (don't forget to backup your EFS files).

I pretty much have the smallest laptop arround, and I am very happy I don't have to carry a laptop bag back and forth to my workplace.

USBoot should work with Windows Vista and 7, yet I haven't had the time to switch (time consuming process for the size and complexity of my stuff).